# Woocommerce checkout page change country doesn't update shipping methods

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

Here is a screencast https://www.screencast.com/t/llJl5QZ8

When country is changed, only payment methods are updated (with ajax), but NOT shipping methods.

I have tried using additional javascript code to force triggering 'update_checkout' but no luck. The code I used was a manual call of jQuery(document.body).trigger('update_checkout') which only triggers payments update but not shipping methods.

Can someone shed a light on possible ways to debug & fix this problem?

Comment: There is certainly something that is making trouble in the checkout page, it can be some customizations that you have made, your themes customizations, or a plugin. You should also check in Woocommerce Status to see if evrything is all right (No red items, like at the end of the page the "template override section).

Comment: same problem here :(